# VS Unit Test Project missing NuGet packages

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, mstest

I am using MSVS Community 2017 (Version 15.8.8) and ReSharper 2018.2.3. I have Unit Test Project (.NET Framework 4.7.1). I push it to repository and clone to another working copy. But Unit Tests do not run and are showing yellow circles with description "Inconclusive test". There is no more info about this error.

What's happening and how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some kind of problem with VS internal cache. There is no problem after deletion of .vs folder within solution. It works for me.